# Copy and Loop using dynamic column number

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to use "j" as a counter for columns.  I tried using it as follows, but in what I have "j" is representing a row.  The macro works, but only copies row 25 - 27.

Can anyone tell me how to use this with j as the column number?  Also, how would I copy this so that the column width is also retained?

```
    Sub CopyFinal()


        Set i = Sheets("MedicalBenefits")
        Set e = Sheets("Final")

        Dim j As Integer
        j = 2

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Do Until IsEmpty(i.Cells(5, j))
            i.Range(j & "5:" & j & "27").Copy e.Range(j & "5:" & j & "27")
            j = j + 1
        Loop

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It isn't clear from the code you've posted, and "use "j" as a counter for columns" is likely only going to get you answers like "you're building range addresses like `15:127`, `24:227`, etc...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch to `Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex)` syntax to use integer columns index

```
    Do Until IsEmpty(i.Cells(5, j))
        i.Cells(5, j).Resize(23).Copy e.Cells(5, j)
        j = j + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you.  I'm very new to VBA so I just looked up resize and will definitely be able to use this moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Offset()`

```
    j = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do Until IsEmpty(range("B5").offset(0,j))
        i.Range("B5:B27").Offset(0,j).Copy e.Range("B5:B27").Offset(0,j)
        j = j + 1
    Loop
```